# I am getting a Gem:LoadError: in the terminal, can someone help me find the source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, terminal, rubygems

I am attempting to run sudo sh  in the terminal. However, I keep getting this error

```
[2014-08-11T10:05:37-04:00] FATAL: Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate httparty-0.13.1, 
because json-1.5.4 conflicts with json (~> 1.8)
```

I have no idea what it means. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

```
FATAL: Gem::LoadError: Unable to activate httparty-0.13.1, 
because json-1.5.4 conflicts with json (~> 1.8)
```

This means you do have json-1.5.4 installed on machine. But httparty-0.13.1 require json 1.8.0 . try update json gem. it will solve your issue.

But do insure dependency of other gem on json-1.5.4 before update json gem

Comment: I'm sorry if my question seems like something I should know the answer too, but what do you mean by insuring dependency? And how would I go about doing it?

Comment: in gemfile.lock you can find json-1.5.4 very easily. If it there just find which gems are depending on it. it would look like a three structure and node is dependent.

Comment: that's assuming the OP is using bundler. It's possibly an rvm install or even compiled straight.

Answer (score 0):

Try update your json gem to `1.8.x`. HTTParty gem requires a json version of `~> 1.8` [link](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/httparty.gemspec#L18). Or downgrade to a HTTParty version that meet with your json gem version.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ruby error. Looks like you have a script set up attached to your (I assume bourne) shell. You need to find that script. I'm no expert but check /etc/profile

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html

The actual error is when whatever is running is run it uses the ruby gem:
httparty-0.13.1 (think library) which requires the gem json 1.8 (there or abouts) but what you have installed is the gem json 1.5.4

If you wanted to fix it you should first look to where you are using json 1.5.4, figure out why it's set to 1.5 ish, and if it breaks anything else. If not I'd upgrade it, with whatever gem management system you're using.

The thing that's odd is that this doesn't sound like you've set up the box, if you knew anything of ruby it'd be obvious. Either someone else maintains it, or you've inherited it, if the former - get them to fix it, if the latter, there are things going on you've no idea about, which is concerning. I'd flatten an undocumented box ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove different versons of json..use `unistall gem json` and then it will ask which to uninstall...its a conflict that needs to be resolved.